# How readelf translate the entry point

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, elf, readelf

I have an elf file, and when I use readelf -h filename I get the entry point.
Now, lets say I want to calculate this address by myself [Using assembly, but the language isn't important].

How can I do that?

I know the the entry point is 4 bytes starting from offset 24 in the file, but I don't know how to translate this data into address.

Comment: There isn't much to translate, that's just your usual 4 byte address in little endian format.

Answer (score 2):

> I know the the entry point is 4 bytes starting from offset 24 in the file, but I don't know how to translate this data into address.

There is no translation necessary when you run on the same target (`x86`) as the one for which the executable has been built.

In pseudo-code, error checking omitted:

```
int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY);
lseek(fd, 24, SEEK_SET);
unsigned long entry_point;
read(fd, &entry_point, sizeof(entry_point));

printf("entry: 0x%lx\n", entry_point);
```

P.S. The 24 is only correct offset for `Elf32`; it's much better to write this portably by reading entire `Elf32_Ehdr` or `Elf64_Ehdr` (depending on byte 5 being `ELFCLASS32` or `ELFCLASS64`) from offset 0, and then using `.e_entry` member.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. If you ask how to read this value from `ELF` file, you should parse ELF file (likely using `libelf` or another existing helper software). If you ask how to form it using some magic on knowledge of the binary program contents, this "magic" is solely calculated from offset of entry how it is compiled into the resulting binary.

The binary in Linux (provided you use standard toolchain, namely, gcc + GNU binutils) is formed as sum of a few input files as the main binary, relocation table for the latter, prolog modules (`crtbegin.o`, `crti.o`), epilog modules (`crtend.o`, `crtn.o`). Entry point is in the prolog but it could be placed by linker after the main binary contents (I see this on /bin/sh on my OpenSuSE) so is really at the end of the resulting binary file. This is linker's right to choose, unless explicitly regulated.